# woocommerce change product permalink to products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have at the moment url in product view: https://mywebsite.com/product/product-name

Shop url looks like this: https://mywebsite.com/shop

I need to change product view url like https://mywebsite.com/products/product-name

I didnt find any settings for that.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this, It is working fine for me

let me know your thoughts..

```
function change_post_types_slug( $args, $post_type ) {   
   if ( 'product' === $post_type ) {
      $args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'products';
   }
   return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'change_post_types_slug', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Permalink structure like the following screenshot will give the intended result.

[image: Permalink Structure]
Link to image: https://snipboard.io/xGJWK6.jpg